# A question about fantasy map making

Tags: map-making, maps

I'm a budding book-writer, YouTuber and game idea person, and I am wanting to make a fantasy map, but alas, I am a broke person. And I am wanting to make a good map for some fantasy/RPG worlds.

Is there any free software that fits my needs? I do plan on getting some good software for it, but I would like a great-quality free one to suit my needs ATM. Are there any good ones I can use for the time being? Any help is appreciated.

God bless you in advance.